# How is it possible to debug ios application and watching logs similar to adb in android?

Tags: android, ios, debugging, adb

I need something to debugging and watching logs on my ios application(.ipa) similar what we have on android adb for watching logcat.
Is it possible ? How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no framework coming from Apple, but lot's of solutions from free to really expensive.
You can try **Google Analytics**, **Crittercism** (probably the most advanced one in terms of crash/performance), **Follow Analytics**. I tried 3 of them and to me Google is a really nice solution (and it's free :-)). You can also implement one yourself. It's not that complex : I just finished one for a client and it took me 3 days (Unit Testing included).